# Cannot create Servlet in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition

Tags: java, intellij-idea, servlets

In the photo you can see that there is no Servlet to create
[image: no servlet]

I looked at the previous answers about the root, but everything is labeled
[image: everything ok there]

There is also a dependency in pom.xml
[image: and here]

So, what could be the problem? Please help me
[image: still no servlet]

Comment: A servlet is just a Java class and an entry in your web.xml. You don't need to do anything special to create one.

Comment: [*Java Platform, Enterprise Edition: The Java EE Tutorial 17.1 What Is a Servlet?*](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/servlets001.htm)

Answer (score 2):

Is it Java Enterprise project?

While creating new project, you need to choose Java Enterprise or Jakarta EE option along with web application template then only you can get servlet option in that list.

1. Create new project.
2. Choose project type as Java Enterprise
3. Template - web application

After following this you can see servlet option in that list.

Else, you can create Java class and directly extend HttpServlet class. You can override all servlet methods in your class.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with version 2023.1, [IntelliJ IDEA removed support for Servlet templates.](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-309062)
But you can manually add a template by following the instructions in the picture:

1. Go to `File | Settings | Editor | File and Code Templates` and add a custom template.
   [image: File | Settings | Editor | File and Code Templates]
2. Paste template code into the field:

```
#if (${PACKAGE_NAME} && ${PACKAGE_NAME} != "")package ${PACKAGE_NAME};#end
#parse("File Header.java")

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.*;
import java.io.IOException;

@WebServlet(name = "${Class_Name}", value = "/${Class_Name}")
public class ${Class_Name} extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    }
}
```

**!!! But** import part depends which package you will use, if you use `Jakarta EE` project, you should import instead of:

```
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.*;
```

this settings:

```
import jakarta.servlet.*;
import jakarta.servlet.http.*;
import jakarta.servlet.annotation.*;
```

3. Now you have own Servlet template in `New` menu.

[image: Servlet in New Menu]

Answer (score 0):

for information.
[IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1 (231.8109.175 build) Release Notes](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/articles/IDEA-A-2100661478/IntelliJ-IDEA-2023.1-231.8109.175-build-Release-Notes)

[image: IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1 (231.8109.175 build) Release Notes]